# Выборка из таблицы строк с первым по времени значением

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть такая таблица. Как сформировать запрос, чтобы получить только первое значение времени из 'time' в каждые сутки?

| name | sub | date | time | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-01 | 08:05:27 | вход |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-01 | 08:07:37 | вход |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-01 | 09:15:01 | вход |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-01 | 11:44:23 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-01 | 08:01:05 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-01 | 09:16:40 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-01 | 10:52:00 | вход |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-02 | 07:58:11 | вход |
| Иванов | охрана | 2021-05-02 | 08:08:28 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-02 | 07:55:44 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-02 | 09:12:16 | вход |
| Петров | маркетинг | 2021-05-02 | 11:14:11 | вход |

Answer (score 1):

> получить только первое значение времени из 'time' в каждые сутки?

```
SELECT `date`, MIN(`time`) time
FROM source_table
GROUP BY `date`
```